# Как правильно хранить JSON в БД при работе с Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, json, база-данных, laravel

Приложение получает пользовательский ввод в формате JSON и сохраняет его в БД, выводит на страницах.
Как правильно работать с JSON в Laravel, в каком виде он должен храниться в БД?
Нужно ли устанавливать тип поля в БД как JSON, экранировать или кодировать его для безопасной работы?

Comment: JSON правильно хранить в поле типа JSON (странно, да?). Если версия СУБД поддерживает такой тип данных, конечно. Иначе - использовать строковые типы (TEXT).

Comment: В случае MySQL следует помнить, что внутренний формат хранения JSON - бинарный, что может приводить к изменению порядка атрибутов в объектах,

Comment: @Akina спасибо за комментарии

Comment: `$table->json('col_name');` а использовать довольно просто, если частично надо сравнить, обновить значение - `...where('col_name->value', 12)...update(['col_name->value' => 13])...`, для извлечения лучше создать [аксессор](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) чтобы сразу массив возвращался (если вам не нужен именно json-объект далее)

Comment: @InDevX спасибо.

В каком именно виде должен храниться JSON в БД?
Сейчас наблюдаю варианты:

1: `\"title\":\"\\u0422\\u0435\\u043a\\u0441\\u0442"`

2: `\"title\":\"Текст\"`

3: `"title":"Текст"`

Comment: @Vyacheslav `$data = ['title'=>'title value']; $json = json_encode($data);`